# Iterate over properties of TypeScript Interface by their type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface in typescript like

```
interface StatusTO {
  name: string,
  identifier: string
}
```

and another one using it like so:

```
export interface RowObject {
  partNumber: string,
  version: string,
  versionCount: number,
  status: StatusTO,
}
```

then, I have a generic search function as following:

```
public isSearchedFor<T extends RowObject>(row: T, key: keyof T, searchTerm: string): boolean {
  let element = row[key];
  let stringValue: string | undefined = undefined;
  switch (key) {
    case 'partNumber':
    case 'version':
      stringValue = (element as string);
      break;
    case 'versionCount':
      stringValue = (element as number).toString();
      break;
    case 'status':
      stringValue = (element as StatusTO).name;
  }
  return stringValue?.includes(searchTerm) ?? false;
}
```

I call it on a

```
row = {
  partNumber: 'You have to FindMe',
  version: '123',
  versionCount: 2,
  status: {
    name: '200',
    identifier: 'OK'
  }
}
```

via `isSearchedFor(row, 'partNumber', 'FindMe');` which will return `true`.

Where there is the switch statement I want iterate over all possible property types of RowObject like 'string', 'number' and 'StatusTO' instead to have it more easily extendable whenever a new property of the same type will be added. The solution of switch all properties of the interface RowObject is not best. How can I automatically handle all properties via their type instead? When only having simple types like string and number I could switch (typeof element). However, I have a complex object type like StatusTO included, so how can I adress this. Best solution would be typesafe, maybe with type guards?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/wXyAJN)?  It's hard to be sure unless you can provide a more illustrative [mre].  Let me know if you want to see that suggestion written up as an answer; or, if not, please [edit] the question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: I found the tsplay example very helpful already. So thanks for that. As mentioned - the solution is primarily based on my own programming - it was surprising to me that ChatGPT suggested the exact same solution where I took more inspiration. I elaborated another example of my own of how to handle enums. There ChatGPT didn't provide working code.

Answer (score 0):

To handle all properties of `RowObject` based on their types, one can use type guards and conditional statements. Here's the `isSearchedFor` function that automatically handles all property types:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean;

function isPrimitive(value: any): value is Primitive {
  return typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number' || typeof value === 'boolean';
}

function isStatusTO(value: any): value is StatusTO {
  return typeof value === 'object' && 'name' in value && 'identifier' in value;
}

function getPropertyAsString(value: any): string {
  if (isPrimitive(value)) {
    return value.toString();
  } else if (isStatusTO(value)) {
    return value.name;
  }

  // Add more type checks and conversions here if needed

  return '';
}

export function isSearchedFor<T extends RowObject>(row: T, key: keyof T, searchTerm: string): boolean {
  const element = row[key];
  const stringValue = getPropertyAsString(element);
  return stringValue.includes(searchTerm);
}
```

In this version, a `isPrimitive` type guard is added to check if a value is a primitive type (`string`, `number`, or `boolean`). Also a `isStatusTO` type guard is added to check if a value is of type `StatusTO`.

The `getPropertyAsString` function handles converting different property types to a string. Currently, it handles primitive types and `StatusTO`. One can add more type checks and conversions to this function if needed.

In the `isSearchedFor` function, the `getPropertyAsString` function is used to get the string representation of the property value. The returned string is then checked if it includes the search term.

This approach allows for easy extensibility when new property types are added to `RowObject`. One can simply add more type guards and conversions to the `getPropertyAsString` function to handle the new types.

One can alternatively use a `switch` statement:

```
function getPropertyAsString(value: any): string {
  switch (typeof value) {
    case 'string':
    case 'number':
    case 'boolean':
      return value.toString();
    case 'object':
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        // Handle array types
        return value.map((item: any) => getPropertyAsString(item)).join(', ');
      } else if ('name' in value && 'identifier' in value) {
        // Handle StatusTO type
        return (value as StatusTO).name;
      }
  }

  return '';
}
```

Here even the recursive handling of arrays was added, so a `string[]` or even a `StatusTO[]` property will be handled perfectly fine.

When having an string enum like:

```
enum YesNoIcon {
  UNDEFINED = 'undefined',
  YES = 'yes',
  NO = 'no'
}
```

then you can export a function like

```
export const isYesNoIcon = (element: any): element is YesNoIcon =>
  !!element
  && Object.values(YesNoIcon).filter(value => isNaN(Number(value))).includes(element);
```

and use it before the switch:

```
// must be before (typeof value === 'string') as it is a string enum
if (isYesNoIcon(value))
{
  return value;
}
```